# Разница между "чувствую" и "ощущаю"

Tags: семантика

Подскажите, существует ли разница между выражениями "Я чувствую себя кем-то" и "Я ощущаю себя кем-то". Довольно часто приходится выбирать один из этих глаголов. Как я понимаю, и чувствовать, и ощущать можно себя каким-нибудь человеком, персонажем, предметом. Также и то, и другое подходит для сравнений, для описаний состояний, для оборотов с наречиями (я чувствую себя прекрасно).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во многих контекстах эти слова взаимозаменяемы, но не всегда более широкое по употреблению "чувствовать" заменимо на "ощущать": например, затруднительно это сделать в выражении "Я чувствую, что пора...[сделать то-то]", где глагол имеет переносный смысл ("склоняюсь к мысли") и грамматически используется как непереходный, что нетипично для глагола "ощущать". Во всяком случае, такая замена придала бы выражению резкую стилистическую окраску ("ощущаю" стало бы здесь сопоставимо с просторечным и физиологичным "нутром чую", в то время как речь идёт об умозаключении).

*В вашем примере* допустимы оба глагола, но оптимальный выбор зависит от контекста: если речь идёт об *обманчивых* ощущениях (не являюсь таким человеком [гением], но чувствую себя таким), то на мой взгляд, предпочтителен глагол "чувствую", если ощущается *реальное* состояние (успешно сдал вступительные экзамены и уже ощущаю себя студентом), примерно равноценны оба варианта, - т. е. и здесь сказывается более широкая употребимость глагола "чувствовать" ("ощущение" обычно *конкретнее* "чувства").